# Perl. Simultaneous match and substitution

Tags: perl, matching, substitution, simultaneous

Im trying to find specific pattern and do substitution in it. And assign result to another variable.

For example:
I have a variable $text with some text in which Im trying to find pattern like "Date:\s+\d{4}.\d\d.\d\d", substitute dots for dashes in it and then assign result to $result.

This version works:

```
($result) = $text =~ /Date:\s+(\d{4}\.\d\d\.\d\d)/igs;
 $result =~ s/\./-/g;
```

But Im trying to do it in one operation. Something like:

```
($result) = $text =~ s/Date:\s+(\d{4})\.(\d\d)\.(\d\d)/$1-$2-$3/igs;
```

But it gives me result "1".
So, the question is: Is it possible to do such thing in one operation? Or what is the best option to do it and minimize code?

Comment: The problem is that the substitution operator can not return capture groups, just the number of times it has matched. Or the entire string after substitution, as mpapec shows, when using the `/r` modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be too keen on writing multiple operations into a single statement: it only serves to spoil the readability of your code. But I suggest that you write something like this.

There is no point in using the `/s` modifier on your original pattern match as it affects only the `.` metacharacter, and there are none of these in your pattern. Also, it makes no sense to use `/g` as you are interested only in a single match.

Don't be tempted to join the two statements into one line, as the `if` statement modifier would then also apply to the `my` declaration which has some very strange effects.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $text = 'Date: 1994.04.04';

my $result;
$result = $1 =~ tr/./-/r if $text =~ /Date:\s+(\d{4}\.\d\d\.\d\d)/i;

say $text;
say $result;
```

**output**

```
Date: 1994.04.04
1994-04-04
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $result;
$text =~ s/Date:\s+(\d{4})\.(\d\d)\.(\d\d)/ $result= "$1-$2-$3" /ei;
```

Comment: Hm. Thanks for reply. It does substitution, but with this I have assigned all text from $text to $result. What Im doing wrong?

Comment: @KingOfFools which part should go into `$result`?

Comment: `/r` makes the substitution return the entire string after substitution.

Comment: @mpapec only date numbers with dashes between. Like "2014-01-01".

Comment: @KingOfFools since there is `/g` should all dates be in `$result`?

Comment: @FilippoLauria only if do is not last expression.

Comment: @mpapec All of the `do` hocus pocus is superfluous.  Can just assign to `$result` directly inside the RHS of the regex. (not addressing the whole whole /g issue of course.)

Comment: @mpapec No. Actually I have just one date in $text that I want to parse. I just copied it from another part of "code".

Comment: @mpapec Yeah, you're right. In fact I was tring `my $result = do { ... } print $result` and it gave me `systax error`. Anyway I think `;` completes the answer.

Comment: @mpapec Your most recent edit is funny :) Although technically it is still two lines.

Comment: Why don't you use `(\d{2})` instead of `(\d\d)`?

Comment: @Miller tnx for comment

Comment: @FilippoLauria that is original regex posted by OP.

Comment: @TLP what do you mean, it was more than two lines before? :)

Comment: @FilippoLauria Don't know. Just because in "\d{2}" more symbols then in "\d\d" I think :)

Comment: @mpapec Well... I meant compared to what the OP wanted. I was playing around with the idea that one could capture the string, and then apply the second regex, like `(($a) = $b =~ /../) =~ tr/./-/` but that does not seem to work.

Comment: @TLP no it doesn't. Perhaps using `..map {} $b =~ /../`?

Comment: Thank you guys for help and explanation. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the parentheses around so that `$text` is first assigned to `$result`, you can then make the substitution apply to `$result` instead of `$text`, and so you can strip all the excess text you do not want, and use your original idea of building the date with dashes `-` instead of dots:

```
(my $result = $text) =~ s/.*Date:\s+(\d{4})\.(\d\d)\.(\d\d).*/$1-$2-$3/igs;
```

Note the use of `.*` at start and end of string, which will consume all of the text, so the only thing left is the date. This line of code is really two operations in one, like so:

```
my $result = $text;
$result =~ s/..../;
```

Another version is to use a post-script `for` loop, which will make use of the fact that `$_` is aliased to the list arguments:

```
tr/./-/ for ((my $result) = $text =~ /Date:\s+([\d.]+)/);
```

This will assign the date to `$result`, and then pass `$result` to the argument list in `for`, applying the transliteration to it. It affects the real variable `$result` because `$_` is aliased within the loop.

Also note that this is really an academic question, in my opinion. I would not recommend using this in production code, and your original is far better and more readable. Although I would use transliteration instead of a substitution:

```
$result =~ tr/./-/;
```

Answer (score 0):

pls try this
($result = $text)=~s/Date:\s+(\d{4}).(\d\d).(\d\d)/$1-$2-$3/igs